# SAPUI5 / OpenUI5 - Load model from manifest

Tags: xml, sapui5, manifest

I am trying to load the Northwind V4 oData Service into my view. I use the tutorial at https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html but it doesn't even work there.
I declared the model in my manifest.json file and want to display the information in a basic table. How should I do this? I tried to set the model in the controller, but it didnt work.

This is my manifest.json. You see, I have declared the model according to the developers guide

```
{
  "_version": "1.1.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "sap.ui.demo.wt",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "dataSources": {
      "invoiceRemote": {
        "uri": "/destinations/northwind/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_hcb",
        "sap_belize"
    ]
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "rootView": "sap.ui.demo.wt.view.App",
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.30",
      "libs": {
        "sap.m": {}
      }
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
          "bundleName": "sap.ui.demo.wt.i18n.i18n"
        }
      },
      "invoice": {
        "dataSource": "invoiceRemote"
      }
    },
    "resources": {
      "css": [
        {
          "uri": "css/style.css"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my xml file, where I want to set the model and display the entries.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="oDataTest2.controller.main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:com="sap.ui.commons">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <Table items="{/value}">
                        <headerToolbar>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <Title text="Categories" level="H2" />
                            </Toolbar>
                        </headerToolbar>
                        <columns>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text ="Category ID" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text="Category Name" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text="Description" />
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem>
                                <cells>
                                    <Text text="{CategoryID}"/>
                                    <Text text="{CategoryName}"/>
                                    <Text text="{Description}"/>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Here is my neo-app.json code

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources",
        "version": "1.44.10"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources",
        "version": "1.44.10"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/destinations/northwind",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "northwind"
      },
      "description": "Northwind OData Service"
    }
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```json
"dataSources": {
    "invoiceRemote": {
        "uri": "/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml",
            "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
    }
}
```

In neo-app.json route:

```json
{
    "path": "/northwind",
    "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "northwind"
    },
}
```

Documentation: *[Create a Northwind Destination](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/3a16c7a2f1e944deb000db49e5ece6be)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URI that you specified in the data source points towards the categories collection (the `Categories` segment at the end of the URI). The OData model URI must point towards the service root path: `/destinations/northwind/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/`.

Also, you are binding your table against the `/value` path. This implies that you expect having an `value` collection. I guess you wanted to bind against the categories collection, so you should change that to `<Table items="{/Categories}">`.

Comment: Hello Serban, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me... Can you check, if the data is loading at https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.26/preview for you? It just displays the error message. If i import this project to my SAP Web IDE, it says "initial loading of metadata failed"..

Comment: @Icjng have you defined the destination in your neo-app.json ?

Comment: @StephenS Yes, I did, according to the mentioned developers guide.

Comment: @Icjng Could you share you neo-app.json code, also can you test the Destination connectivity in the HCP cockpit ?

Comment: @StephenS The destination works. I attached the code to my question